# Drupal node path with taxonomy term id

Tags: drupal-7, taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy, pathauto

I have two vocabularies: country and type

Country terms:
tid = 1
name = USA
...

Type terms:
tid = 10
name = students

I need to generate node path next way (terms id instead of names):
study/1/10/[node-title]
study/2/10/[node-title]

I have only this option:
study/[node:field_country]/[node:field_type]]/[node-title]

Is there any way to make
study/[tid-1]/[tid-2]/[node-title] ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using pathauto module

1-enable pathauto module

2-go to `http://example.com/admin/config/search/path/patterns`

3-expand `TAXONOMY TERM PATHS`

4-change `[term:vocabulary]/[term:name]` with `[term:vocabulary:vid]/[term:tid]`

good luck

Comment: I am actually looking it for Drupal 7. I'm using pathauto of course, but I don't see option wit term id, only term name. That is my problem

Comment: please make sure that `Token` module is enabled

Comment: Then it should work, no other modules are required to accomplish this functionality

Comment: It seems that you do not understand me. I have term:vocabulary and term:name but not in patterns for node, only for terms. I need it to nodes, NODES